# How do i fix my maven installation problems?

Tags: java, maven, terminal

I am receiving three problems while trying to install maven on my mac.  I am typing:

```
mvn -v
```

in the terminal and receive

```
line 45: uname: command not found ; 

line 66: dirname: command not found

Error: Could not find or load main class
 org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
```

I am running on a Mac and followed the directions to install Maven on their site.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell where you have installed Maven on Mac? How exactly did you done it? Please show a directory listing via `ls -al` ...?

Comment: What _directions_ did you follow exactly?

Comment: Kindly add detailed instructions that you followed to install maven. Moreover, you should use `brew` which is a great package installer for mac.